# googletranslate() on Google Sheets output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

I am trying to translate many rows of sentences using the googletranslate()  function on Google Sheets as a shortcut.

If I do this manually on the Google Translate website, I generally get two possible outputs with one being more grammatically correct. When I use googletrasnalte() I get the less grammatically correct.

Why is that and is there a way of changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and it is a design decision by Google to use the older translation feature. See this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/178959844. Perhaps you could create a Feature Request to have the better translation. If so you could do it in the the same public Issue Tracker and clicking on the "Create Issue" button.